# Django POST variables not being created

Tags: python, django

I have a weird problem, I have been asked to modify a Django form to include an address (simple I thought), the original html form collects the data, name, contact, etc and then the views.py gets the POST variables using sender_name = request.POST.get('sender_name', ''), etc.

The sender_address which is a textarea on the HTML form is not included in the POST dictionary. I can see all the other POST variables. The weird thing is if I change one of the original POST variables (name) in the HTML form, example sender_name to sender_name1, it also stops working and disappears from the dictionary.

I’m new to Django, slowly getting my head around it, is there a way in django to protect the POST variables or am I completely missing something.  The form data is not being stored in a dB its being fired off in an email.  There isn’t any forms.py associated with the view either.

Thank you.

```
 <div class="wishlist_form">
    <form method="POST" action="/store/wish-list-request/">{% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            <tr style="vertical-align:top">
                <td>YOUR NAME:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="sender_name" name="sender_name" class="input" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="vertical-align:top">
                <td>YOUR ADDRESS:</td>
                <td><textarea id="sender_address" name="sender_address" ></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="vertical-align:top">
                <td>YOUR EMAIL:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="sender_email" name="sender_email" class="input" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="vertical-align:top">
                <td>CONTACT NUMBER:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="sender_number" name="sender_number" class="input" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="vertical-align:top">
                <td>COMMENT:</td>
                <td><textarea id="sender_comment" name="sender_comment"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="vertical-align:top">
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit your wish list &raquo;" class="wishlist_submit_btn">
                    <div id="ResponseDiv"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="wishlist_objects" id="wishlist_objects" value="{% for item in list %}{{ item.article }}{% if not forloop.last %}|{% else %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="hack" id="hack" value="" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

```
@csrf_exempt
def send_wishlist(request):
    hack = request.POST.get('hack', '')
    subject = "Wish List Order From Website"
    sender_email = request.POST.get('sender_email', '')
    sender_name = request.POST.get('sender_name', '')
    sender_address = request.POST.get('sender_address',)
    sender_number = request.POST.get('sender_number', '')
    sender_comment = request.POST.get('sender_comment', '')
    wishlist_objects = request.POST.get('wishlist_objects', '')

    if len(hack) > 0 : #hacker, so fail here
      return HttpResponse('Website notification error of Invalid header found.')

    if subject and sender_email and sender_name and sender_number and wishlist_objects:
        message = "Hi admin,\nNew Wish List Order From Website\n\n"
        message += "Customer Name: "  + sender_name + "\n";
        message += "Customer Address: " + sender_address + "\n";
        message += "Customer Email: "  + sender_email + "\n";
        message += "Customer Number: "  + sender_number + "\n\n";
        message += "Customer Comment:\n"  + sender_comment + "\n\n";
        message += "--------------------------------------------\n\n";

        try:
            sender="noreply@xxxx.xxx"
            recipients=['xxx@xxxx.xxxx']
            list = wishlist_objects.split('|')
            for item in list:
                message += "Article Number: "  + item + "\n";
                message += "\n";
                message += "--------------------------------------------";
                message += "\n\n";

            send_mail(subject, message, sender, recipients, fail_silently=False, auth_user=None,
auth_password=None)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/store/wishlist/thanks/')
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Sending mail failed because' + BadHeaderError)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid details provided - please go back and re-enter.' )
```

Comment: We can't possibly help unless you show us the exact code you're using.

Comment: You are not using sessions but a POST request. On a first sight your code seems ok.

Comment: The sender_address is blank and if I change any of the other variables in the html it too disappears and ends up being blank.  I'm running a debugger in Pycharm to see the values.

Comment: Is the form submitted as plain HTML or is there any JavaScript involved or used on the page?

Comment: Thanks @JanMalte there was a base.js being called by the base.py which was writing the POST data.  Thanks for pushing me in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JanMalte for pushing me in the right direction, it's finally solved!! There was a base.js which had a function loadstoreinfo() being called which was writing the POST data.

Comment: Please write non-answers as comments and not as an answer.